# Interesting and unusual dependent variable--how do you think it should be handled?

Tags: distributions, likert, scales, dependent-variable, scale-construction

We have 2 dependent measures, which are both distributed from -4 to +4 in discrete steps. This is because the values are based on people's responses to four questions about whether they spend more time doing something of type X or type Y.

They either scored +1 or -1 for each answer... basically, someone who *always* spends more time doing something of type X vs. Y would have a +4 score, indicating they are on one end of a spectrum of time-usage, whereas someone who always spends more time doing something of type Y vs. X would end up with a -4 score, indicating they're on the opposite end of that spectrum.

You can see the histogram for these variables below:

[image][image]

The scores in red actually look rather normally distributed (they are discrete though), the ones in blue somewhat less so.

We now want to compare different groups of respondents (e.g., males versus females) on these scores. I would normally just do some type of general linear model for this, but because the way the scores were derived is unusual and the data are so bounded and discrete, I am hesitating...

I started to think that in a WAY this is like Likert data, and then I know people really balk at using things like ANOVA for that. What do you think? If you think ANOVA or some other general linear model is *not* appropriate for these data, what **WOULD** you suggest to do, to compare subgroups of respondents?

Thanks so much!

Comment: If these are proxies for time, then does the use of time in one preclude the use of time in the second variable?

Comment: Have you thought of ordinal logistic models?

Comment: Actually only the first (red) variable is about time, the other (blue) is about format--so the two things are completely orthogonal (in theory).

Comment: You're thinking treat it as ordinal, something like: if -4 is the lowest score, treat that as the lowest rank, and then work up in order to a +4? I suppose that would make sense, too!